# How to Fix "Failed to send your message" in Contact FORM 7 on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, contact-form, contact-form-7

Hello I have Contact Form 7. It was working nicely. I wanted to add captcha to my form so contact form 7 has an option to add captcha but it requires integration with settings. I followed the same mentioned steps. I went to Google’s reCAPTCHA admin page, Registered my website and got site key and secret key then added those keys to wp-admin `Contact > Integration` and save them. Then my contact form was not working.

Then i opened the `mail` tab in my contact form 7. I have lots all the settings. not sure what settings to use.

I have two version of site, one is live and one is demo site. So I have copied the `mail` settings of demo to live site. Copied exactly the same settings.

My demo's FROM setting contains this

`[your-name] <wordpress@demo.lmdemo.com>`

For example this is my demo site `demo.lmdemo.com` so added `<wordpress@demo.lmdemo.com>` in FROM Section.

but my contact form is giving me this error

`Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method.`

What I have done so far.

- I have tested on default theme, still giving me same error.
- I have deactivated all other plugins, still giving me same error.
- I have deactivated Contact form 7, and activated again, still same
  error.

Contact form on my demo site is working perfectly, but not on live website. Contact form has same settings on demo and live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting it very late, I have fixed my issue. There were lot of spaming emails i was receiving and my hosting provider has blocked something that's why I was getting this error.

> Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the
>   administrator by another method.

So I have added captacha, It was still not working, so I have just email them to fix the issue on their end and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

just deactivated Akismet plugin and change } instead of a ], then you are able to send and receive a message to your website's email address from your system. otherwise recreate contact forms....... it works for me.

Comment: Where should i change } instead of a ]? and akismet is already deactivated. I will try make new forms.

Comment: Just make sure in the email field use the field name as your-email (or name you are using )

[email* your-email id:InputEmail class:form-control placeholder "email"]

Comment: Im using `[email* your-email class:form-control]` and here is screenshot of mail tab. http://prntscr.com/bajgq1

Comment: enter your email on your-email field i mean check your email address is correct or...?

Comment: Where i enter email address? in mail tab?

Comment: in first field  "to" you wrote  an address  is correct or not

Comment: It is correct, I was getting emails on it before but not getting emails now. in `to` field it is my email written `info@landmarkdoha.com`

Comment: i think you have another problem, you need to remove your cache first and  then recheck...

Comment: Just new to wp, how to remove cache?

Comment: press  ctrl+shift+delete

Comment: oh!..... Open wp-config.php and add below line to permanently disable cache in  and 2ndly .0.2.

define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);